# Kubernetes on 32 bit machine

Tags: linux, kubernetes, 32bit-64bit

While I was running kubectl command in my ubuntu 16.04 os which is a 32 bit machine, I was getting

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Can some one tell me whether Kubernetes works on 32 bit machine or not ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no ready-made binaries for 32bit systems at: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.7.md#downloads-for-v1710

You can build kubernetes from source though: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/binary_release/#building-from-source

As a commenter mentioned, there is support for 32bit systems for the client tool, kubectl: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.7.md#client-binaries

Comment: The link you provided has _client_ downloadfiles for 32 bit architectures. While kubernetes _server_ is 64 bit only, the `kubectl` mentioned by the OP is available as 32 bit.